# VueJS - Can not use keyword 'await' outside an async function

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have this code and I am getting this error - "Can not use keyword 'await' outside an async function":

```
async login() {
                try {
                    this.$validator.validateAll().then((result) => {
                        if (result) {
                            this.state = 'LOADING';
                            this.response = [];
                            const authResponse = await axios.post('/api/auth/login', this.user);
                            const auth = authResponse.data;

                            if (auth.success) {
                                this.$authLoggedIn(auth);
                                this.$authRedirectToDefault();
                            } else {
                                this.response.push(auth.error);
                                this.state = 'ERROR';
                            }
                        }
                    });
                } catch (error) {
                    this.state = 'ERROR';
                    this.response.push(error);
                }
            },
```

How can I resolve this? Been stuck on this for a couple of hours.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to unwrap the promise yourself with `.then`, since you are already in an async function. When you use `.then((result) => {...})` that arrow function is not async anymore. My suggestion:

```
  try {
    const result = await this.$validator.validateAll()
    if (result) {
      this.state = 'LOADING';
      this.response = [];
      const authResponse = await axios.post('/api/auth/login', this.user);
      const auth = authResponse.data;

      if (auth.success) {
        this.$authLoggedIn(auth);
        this.$authRedirectToDefault();
      } else {
        this.response.push(auth.error);
        this.state = 'ERROR';
      }
    }
  } catch (error) {
    this.state = 'ERROR';
    this.response.push(error);
  }
```

Alternatively, you can mark the arrow function as async by doing:

```
this.$validator.validateAll().then(async (result) => {
```

Answer (score 1):

we know that `async..await` is pair keyword,

Just you have used `async` in your upper function.your inner function has not async keyword, but you have used `await` inside the function. thats why it is showing error. just i marked the function that is not `async`

```
(result)/*this function has not async*/ => {
                        if (result) {
                            this.state = 'LOADING';
                            this.response = [];
                            const authResponse = await axios.post('/api/auth/login', this.user);
                            const auth = authResponse.data;

                            if (auth.success) {
                                this.$authLoggedIn(auth);
                                this.$authRedirectToDefault();
                            } else {
                                this.response.push(auth.error);
                                this.state = 'ERROR';
                            }
                        }
                    });
```

so you have to use async keyword into inner function.

> async (result) => { /* your code here */  }

Answer (score 0):

The login function already async function, you can call this.$validator with await instead .then(). because inside .then(() => {}) is another callback function not async function.
This is my suggestion:

````
try {
    let result = await this.$validator.validateAll();
    if (result) {
      this.state = 'LOADING';
      this.response = [];
      const authResponse = await axios.post('/api/auth/login', this.user);
      const auth = authResponse.data;

      if (auth.success) {
        this.$authLoggedIn(auth);
        this.$authRedirectToDefault();
      } else {
        this.response.push(auth.error);
        this.state = 'ERROR';
      }
    }
  } catch (error) {
    this.state = 'ERROR';
    this.response.push(error);
  }```
````